# Always run Firefox ESR in Wayland instead of X.org on Debian

Tags: debian, xorg, firefox, wayland, .desktop

When using the latest stable desktop environment, to enable features like screen share inside of video conference programs, and for stability, Wayland seems to work better than the ancient X.org.

I can use this command in the terminal

```bsh
MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 firefox
```

but how can I force Firefox ESR to always start in Wayland mode by default when the launcher is used, or simply by calling `firefox` from the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in both Debian Stable (currently bullseye) and Debian Testing (currently bookworm)!

1. Edit `/usr/bin/firefox` and merge the following

```bsh
    #!/bin/sh                                                                                               
    
    FIREFOX="$(command -v firefox)"
    [ -x "$FIREFOX.real" ] && exec "$FIREFOX.real" "$@"
    
    exec env MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 firefox-esr "$@"
```

This will force the binary to always start in Wayland mode (useful for calling `firefox` in the terminal)

2. Edit `/usr/share/applications/firefox-esr.desktop` to make the `Exec` line

```bsh
    Exec=env MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr %u
```

This will ensure the launcher also starts the browser in Wayland mode.

Comment: Shouldn't this be reported as a bug? I'd expect the `firefox-esr` to run adaptively both under X11 and Wayland (with functional remoting for both cases; that is not the case now).

Comment: @eudoxos
I guess Debian's conservative philosophy of not changing it, they wont bother. Firefox obviously included the feature, but also probably wont want to change it because -esr is supposed to be super stable
It works fine in xwayland mode, minus the fact you can't do something like share screen in Jitsi/Zoom type websites, and probably other I/O integration
looks like we're stuck with this method for a while (I return to this question every time I reinstall OS on any computer)